# TextArea on form only taking a maximum of 50 characters?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

When a user tries to enter a review in "textarea" in the form, only 50 characters of review is displayed. I have tried resolving the situation by disabling Jquery form validation changing the field type to tinytext, mediumtext. I am able to enter the full review 200 characters via PHPMyAdmin so I am guessing the problem is with my PHP but I am not able to see anything obvious . If any one could help it would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <label for="review">Your Review</label>
    <br/>
    <textarea name="review" id="review" rows="15" cols="60"></textarea>


     // Check for a review
if (empty($_POST['review'])){
    $errors[] = "Please write a review";
} else {
    $review = (trim($_POST['review']));
} 


if (empty($errors)) { // If no errors were found.

    require_once('./includes/mysql_connect.php');

    // Make the insert query.
    $query = "INSERT INTO films (movie_title, actor, rating, user_id)
    Values ('$mt', '$la', '$rating', '$user')";

    $result = mysql_query($query);

    $id = mysql_insert_id();

    $query = "INSERT INTO reviewed (review, movie_id)
    values ('$review', '$id')";

    $result = mysql_query($query);



    <div id="Review_container">

    <?php
    require_once('./includes/mysql_connect.php');
    $review = $_GET['id'];
    echo $review;
    ?>
    </div>




 Table structure for table `reviewed`


 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `reviewed` (
 `review_id` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `review` mediumtext NOT NULL,
 `movie_id` int(4) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`review_id`),
 KEY `movie_id` (`movie_id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;


  //No value for review
    if ($('#review').val() == "") {
        $('.error').append("<li>Please enter a review</li>");
        error = true;
    }

    if (error) { // If error found dont submit.
        e.preventDefault();
    }
   }); // End of .submit function: review_a_film.php
```

Comment: Can you show your javascript?

Comment: //No value for review
        if ($('#review').val() == "") {
            $('.error').append("<li>Please enter a review</li>");
            error = true;
        }

        if (error) { // If error found dont submit.
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }); // End of .submit function: review_a_film.php

Comment: when you add the review with the form, the review is at 200 characters in the database ?

Comment: Is that all the code? Doesn't look like it is anything you are showing now

Comment: No in the Datebase it's 50 characters for a review when going via the form.

Comment: I have added the Jquery to the bottom of the pulldown element in overflow.

Comment: It seems that the users are using copy and paste in the text area, any reason why Chrome doesn't like this ??